# grouping by parameters in postgres sql function and returning column name identical to the parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query

```
select count(distinct id), usertype from mytable group by usertype;
```

which I want to wrap in a function where usertype is a parameter

```
create or replace function myfun(facet text)
RETURNS TABLE(total_accounts bigint, facet text)

LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    select count(distinct id), facet from mytable group by facet;
$$;
select * from myfun('usertype');
```

so that output column name also depends on the parameter I send.

But it shows an error 'parameter facet is used more than once'.

how do I make the output identical to the original query when I pass 'usertype' as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic query in a plpgsql function :

```
create or replace function myfun(OUT total_accounts bigint, INOUT facet text)
RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
    select count(distinct id),' || quote_ident(facet) || ' from mytable group by ' || quote_ident(facet) ;
END ;
$$;

select * from myfun('usertype');
```

test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bb5a24bbd97a6979a9fbf40aaf55a9a8)

Comment: hmm it still gives an error 'parameter facet used more than once'...

Comment: this is because you have an input parameter and an output parameters called 'facet'. I've changed the declaration of your function in order to make it working now, see the updated answer and the test in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bb5a24bbd97a6979a9fbf40aaf55a9a8)